# How to loop a double-conditional over a vector

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Halloo! I've hit a snag trying to automate an ifelse statement with two conditions... I've generated a fake value for every minute in a day and want to group values by intervals - hourly, every 5 mins, every twenty, whathaveyou - but the only way I've been able thus far to group by these intervals is brute force:

```
d$hourly <- ifelse(d$t >= 0 & d$t <= 60, 0, 
       ifelse(d$t > 60 & d$t <= 120, 1, 
       ifelse(d$t > 121 & d$t <= 180, 2, 
       ifelse(d$t > 180 & d$t <= 240, 3, 
       ifelse(d$t > 240 & d$t <= 300, 4,
       ifelse(d$t > 300 & d$t <= 360, 5,
       ifelse(d$t > 360 & d$t <= 420, 6, 
       ifelse(d$t > 420 & d$t <= 480, 7, 
       ifelse(d$t > 480 & d$t <= 520, 8,
       ifelse(d$t > 520 & d$t <= 600, 9,
       ifelse(d$t > 600 & d$t <= 660, 10,
       ifelse(d$t > 660 & d$t <= 720, 11, 
       ifelse(d$t > 720 & d$t <= 780, 12, 
       ifelse(d$t > 780 & d$t <= 840, 13, 
       ifelse(d$t > 840 & d$t <= 900, 14, 
       ifelse(d$t > 900 & d$t <= 960, 15,
       ifelse(d$t > 960 & d$t <= 1020, 16,
       ifelse(d$t > 1020 & d$t <= 1080, 17,                                     
       ifelse(d$t > 1080 & d$t <= 1140, 18, 
       ifelse(d$t > 1140 & d$t <= 1200, 19,
       ifelse(d$t > 1200 & d$t <= 1260, 20, 
       ifelse(d$t > 1260 & d$t <= 1320, 21,                                     
       ifelse(d$t > 1320 & d$t <= 1380, 22, 
       ifelse(d$t > 1380 & d$t <= 1440, 23, NA))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

presumably, there is something I am not understanding about for(i in 1:nrow) or other looped functions. Is there a cleaner way to loop conditionals over a vector?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can just divide by 60 can't you?

```r
d  <- data.frame(t = seq(0:1439))

d$hourly  <- floor(d$t/60)

head(d)
#   t hourly
# 1 1      0
# 2 2      0
# 3 3      0
# 4 4      0
# 5 5      0
# 6 6      0

tail(d)
#         t hourly
# 1435 1435     23
# 1436 1436     23
# 1437 1437     23
# 1438 1438     23
# 1439 1439     23
# 1440 1440     24
```

Comment: Oh wow! Brilliant!! I had played with dividing by my desired interval but the floor function was unbeknownst to me.. thank you so much!!